# long arithmetic in C

Tags: c, long-integer, algebraic-data-types

can you divide two long datatypes and turn them into a fraction? If not, would you have to type convert the datatypes into floats? Can someone explain how long arithmetic works in C.

This is a snippet of my code, the datatypes of denominator and numerator are long.

```
float sum=0;
for (i=0; i < num+1 ; i++) {
    denominator = factorial(i);
    printf("%ld\n",denominator);
    sum+=(numerator/denominator);
    printf("\n%f\n",sum);
}
```

Comment: Look at the modulo binary operator %

Comment: Hmmm ==>`(double)numerator/denominator`

Comment: Dividing integers always returns an integer. You need to cast one of them to `float` or `double` to get a floating point result.

Comment: @franji1 I ended up just type converting the numerator to float and it worked. What do you mean by modulo operator?

Comment: Modulo operator gives you the remainder when you divide.  So 20 % 7 is 6.  So you can end up with the 3 integer portions of the simplification of integer division (the whole, the remainder numerator and the remainder denominator) by using integer divide and integer mod.